# RTS game database/data-storage structure

Tags: c#, sql, database, database-design

How do I best and most efficiently structure a database for an RTS game with units, buildings and resources?

I am looking into making a RTS game and hit a bit of a snag, I am struggling with finding a suitable way of storing UserData.

---

The style of the game is a real time strategy game in the lines of the popular mobile games "boom beach" and "clash of clans" and will have a somewhat similar structure of unit groups, defense buildings and recourse/passive buildings and a user base.

---

I have thought of several solution, none of which suitable for thousands or hundreds of thousands of users. The worst data to store is the base and all the objects on it, those being defense/resource/passive buildings, walls, trees.

Lets say we have possibly 15 defense structures and about 5-10 passive/recourse buildings as well as a bunch of defense walls (maybe 10-20) and we have some vegetation on the map in form of trees, there might be in a range from 5-50 trees, as well as the groups of units (4-8 groups pr user), all that times the amount of users, extreme case 400k - 1m, that's going to be an insane amount of rows in a table and will cause some performance drop when maybe 10-20% of those users are online and making changes.

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't a StackOverflow question. Maybe a [GameDev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) question? Also, it's pretty ambitious to assume 1 million users.. though it guess it doesn't hurt to have a scalable solution.

Comment: I know its a large number, and I know it might never get to this point, but its more a question of good quality, and for the GameDev, can I just paste the question there instead? not sure if that's bad practice xD

Comment: @Quantic The game description just gives the background for the database requirements. The core of the question is about datbases all right.

Simon: Please clarify what you need to store and how frequently. The entire game history, or just the current status of a game? Every minute/second/millisecond or what? Only on user request or permanently in the background? How frequently will those data have to be retrieved, and what is an acceptable response time for that?

Comment: @SimonJensen did you find a solution for this? I am stuck in a similar position. I was considering Redis, however it looks like Redis doesn't support huge loads of data to be loaded on initial loads. However it works great when you need to set/get single objects since you can do almost 100k transactions/second.